# Is there a programmable way to dertermine if a <div> is overflow

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

```
<div id="container">
  some content
</div>
```

Say the container div is resizable, while resizing how do I know if it's already overflowed( inner content width < container width or inner content height < container height )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the only way is to compare the

[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight) < [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight)

for vertical scrollbar

and

[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) < [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollWidth)

for horizontal scrollbar.